# Thoughts on the [info], [information], and [advice] tags?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request, ambiguous-tags

These three tags:

- [info](/questions/tagged/info) with 69 questions
- [information](/questions/tagged/information) with 126 questions
- [advice](/questions/tagged/advice) with 116 questions

appear to be ambiguous (in application to a wide variety of unrelated topics) and really serve as metaphors for:

- Could you provide me with more [info](/questions/tagged/info)?
- How about some [advice](/questions/tagged/advice)?

Could they be blacklisted, or at least removed? Thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

Kill. Kill. Kill. Destroy. Destroy. Destroy. None of them add any real value. By eliminating easy-to-use-and-apply-to-anything tags like this you force the OP to think more carefully about the careful tagging of their question.

To me, none of them when used in that form add any more value than having a tag saying [need-help](/questions/tagged/need-help).

Comment: Excellent point about the side benefits of eliminating such inviting and easy-to-use tags.

Comment: Perhaps just as surprising as the 22 following [tag:advice]?

Comment: @Cody & slugster, should I add [tag:tool-advice] **x 28** [tag:application-advice] **x 24** [tag:library-advice] **x 7** too?

Comment: @M.Tibbits: Looks like you already solved the [tag:tooladvice] and [tag:applicationadvice] problem. I agree those tags aren't particularly informative... Perhaps [tag:library-advice] should be a synonym for [tag:libraries] (which does at least convey some information about the problem).

Answer (score 1):

I think that [information](/questions/tagged/information) is useless, when it's used in questions such as the following ones:

- [Issue with FileWriter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6884490/issue-with-filewriter)
- [PHP GZIP more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6793724/php-gzip-more-information)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6378709/how-to-load-info-from-a-php-based-server-in-ios-app

The tag seems used when the OP is asking information (which question is not asking information?) or when the topic of the question is information displayed from some code. It is a too generic tag that doesn't seem to be useful.
Are there any expert of information that are following the tag? Are there any users that filters the questions basing on that tag?
The most important question is then: How useful is a tag if it applies to the majority of the questions asked on a SE site?

Comment: Surprisingly, there *are* 7 people who follow the [tag:information] tag. I'm not sure why, as I agree it's useless.